# Visual Studio 2010 C# How to add pictures that go below other pictures

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, picturebox

So basically, I want to add two pictures. One of them is an outline and the other is card.

The outline has the same number of pixels of surface as the card, but it has a little extra where the outline actually is. So basically, it's a card with an outline but it's split into an outline picture and a card picture.

So how do I make it so that the center part of the outline picture is transparent, so that the card can fit inside it?

I can't make the outline of the card and the card into one picture because I need the outline to flash by using it's "visible" property. If I make the image transparent it'll just show the form's background.

Here is what I want to do for those who don't understand yet:

[image]

This has to fit inside this:

[image]

But when I put the card in the outline (even if the insides of the outline is transparent) the card will disappear into it because it goes into the background and doesn't stay surfaced. I need it to fit right into the outline but it won't work.

Comment: How about telling us what you're actually using instead of your IDE? Asp.net? WPF? WinForms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a method that creates a new bitmap with the two images drawn on top of eachother. Like this:

```
Bitmap DrawCardWithOutline(Image card, Image outline)
{
    /// Put null checks here.

    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(outline.Width, outline.Height);
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result))
    {
        Rectangle cardRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, result.Width, result.Height);
        graphics.DrawImage(card, cardRect);

        Rectangle outlineRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, result.Width, result.Height);
        graphics.DrawImage(outline, outlineRect);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Adjust the `cardRect` (`Rectangle`) to match where you want to show your card. In my example the card is drawn from the top-left corner (0,0) all the way to the bottom-right corner (width, height).

Use it like this:

```
var card = Image.FromFile(@"C:\card.png");
var outline = Image.FromFile(@"C:\outline.png");
var result = DrawCardWithOutline(card, outline);
pictureBox1.Image = result;
```

Store the result of `DrawCardWithOutline` if you need to use it again soon, as creating a new bitmap is not a cheap operation. For example, you can switch between the `card` and the `result` images to simulate flashing.

Comment: you'll want to reverse the order you draw those in.  Draw the outline first so that the card is on top of it.

Comment: The OP talked about the outline having a transparent inside. So this is the correct order.

Comment: Perhaps, Perhaps Not.  My understanding of Bitmaps is that they dont support transparency, and you are drawing on a bitmap.  In fact, you are creating rectangles on a bitmap, which are not naturally transparent to my knowledge...the second rectangle will itself hide the first.  Also, the rectangle for the Card should have its height and width decreased by the same amount that the inner corner is offset by.  for your example it works fine (0,0), but if its offset 10 then you need width-10 and height-10

Comment: Your understanding of bitmaps and my code is completely backwards. First: we're talking about the `Bitmap` class here (which supports transparency), and you (I think) are talking about the completely unrelated `.bmp` bitmap files. Second: the `Rectangle` objects _don't draw anything_: they specify the area in which the image is drawn. Your comment about the size of the rectangle is correct, but I think that's only logical. Finally: I tested this _with transparency_ and it works as expected. :D

Comment: My apologies then, and thank for clearing that up.  That being said...it still seems to me like, regardless of whether it would work or not, the better logic would be to draw the outline before drawing the card.  Assume a wider scope and that the outline doesn't use a transparent fill, or that there are multiple outlines he gets from an external source and cannot guarantee they will be transparent, etc etc and so on.  perhaps that's just a difference of opinion though.

Comment: Your opinion is valid and it is certainly not wrong to do it the other way around. I always put the non-transparent images at the bottom. I imagine this as if you put a card in a (semi-)transparent sleeve. In this case the sleeve has just a red border, but I could also imagine a border glow effect or some nice line art on it. If you were to draw the other way around, you would always obscure this. But indeed, it's just a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

work with your Z-Orders.  Make sure that the Card is on top of the Outline, and that the margins and padding for the card and outline are both set to 0.

Alternatively...

Work with the PictureBox Border settings.  you can change the thickness and color of the border, and turn the border on and off with a timer.  That way you can, instead of drawing two images or using a separate picture for the outline, literally turn on the outline of the pictureBox itself.